# I don't understand this audit.

Tags: discussion, review-audit, deleted-answers, disputed-review-audits

Recently, when going through the Low Quality Posts review queue, [I failed an audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1207113). Of course, audits have notoriously been inaccurate at times and I have failed other review audits before, but those times I could at least see why I might have made a decision contrary to what others would have made. Maybe an answer was wrong and I didn't catch the mistake, or maybe the answer simply restated what another answer already addressed and I did not realise, for example.

[image]

This is the first time I am completely puzzled by the logic of the audit. The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/reference-for-algebraic-geometry/3222578#3222578) asks for book recommendations on algebraic geometry, and as far as I can tell that's what the answer in the audit provided. I definitely cannot see how the answer is supposedly "spam or offensive". I don't know about the contents of the book, nor do I have sufficient background to understand any  of it, but from the Amazon preview it seems to be a perfectly serious, perfectly legitimate textbook. At worst, it might be a horribly written, completely inaccessible text, but that does not make it spam or worthy of deletion, as far as I can tell.

Can anyone explain what the logic might be behind deleting this particular answer?

(To be clear, I am not that upset about failing an audit per se, nor is the purpose of this post about improving the audit system. I really just do not understand the logic behind the deletion of the answer and hope I can get an explanation here.)

Comment: As far as I understand, spam deletions can be automatic if there are enough flags.

Comment: It seems plausible that this was a case of self-promotion by the author, given that the answer appeared a mere 11 days after the publication of the book.

Comment: @EricWofsey That was my first thought too, but there's no way to verify if that were the case (none that I am aware of, anyway). In either case, even if it were an instance of self-promotion, IMHO that does not justify deletion if the book answers the question.

Comment: @MattSamuel I see, I didn't know that. Is there any way for us to verify whether that was what actually happened?

Comment: Maybe there is,but I don't know of one.

Comment: I've seen this user posting a ton of answers (at least 10) promoting the same book. Doubtlessly, it is spam. His account is deleted, possibly due to too many promotional contents.

Comment: How many answers in a ton?

Comment: Same thing happened to me with the same post.

Comment: In addition to the shameless self-promotion, the link seems to contain a referral, which means that the person posting it (potentially) makes some small amount of money if the book is purchased after someone follows the link.  It is a subtle kind of spam, but it is spam, nevertheless.

Comment: Here's [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222627/90543) not from an audit, but also deleted and locked by the Community user. It's quite possible the user searched for questions asking for AG references and spammed links to the book everywhere. Even the wording of the two answers is identical. That said, it's hard to tell its spam in the review queue, since it does appear to answer the question. I would have had no idea that the "ref =stuff" part of the url was a referral. I recently failed a very similar review as well. Luckily one review failure doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I see, thanks all for the responses. Would any of you like to make this an answer (just so this question could be marked as answered)?

Comment: Interestingly, I have gotten this exact audit twice!

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Did you pass it the second time? :P

Comment: I passed it both times since it was very evident that it is an audit.

Comment: This same thing has happened to me. Silly nonsense.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: Did you get the *same audit*, or audited identical answers?

Comment: This exact answer and I am very sure that both were on the same question. I can't even check my previous reviews because I have dropped down to 1860 rep from 2060. Is there any reason why those posts are being deleted? I had a +8 answer on one so I am very confused. I thought that questions with upvoted answers shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is much [consensus](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30236/review-audits-posts-with-links/30238?noredirect=1#comment130505_30238) on what should be done when a post has links. At any rate, I tend to side with the OP in this case.

Comment: @Mohammad: Upon digging into the history of audits, the two audits you mention were on different answers to different questions. Which is also different from the one in this OP.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So the same user answered 3 different questions with the same answer?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: Apparently.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think it is a fair audit. I would never have known that and since it was on a resource request question, I might even have let it pass. Is there anyway to remove questions from the audit list? Also, why are so many questions being deleted all of a sudden? I have dropped down 200 rep and that is very surprising to me.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan The audits are automatically generated.  I don't know who (if anyone) has the power to remove an audit from the list (cue Martin Sleziak with a list of links in 3... 2... ).  However, there is a [meta thread for collecting poor audits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am curious as to why that thread exists if no one has the power to remove an audit...

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan If you read the thread, it states:

"This serves both the purpose of getting at least a small idea of the scale of this (ie, how often does it happen), and also means that we will potentially get information enough to suggest concrete changes to the algorithms used for picking the audit cases (if this seems necessary)."

Comment: Maybe someone should have the power, i.e. the site moderators? Maybe the develepors?

Comment: developers * but in a community moderated by anyone above a certain reputation, only the highest moderators should have it. But then they get overworked. which then defeats the point in a large online community.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to get this question off the unasnwered list, here's the explanation (thanks to YuiTo Cheng, Xander Henderson, jgon and other commenters for the help). It turns out that the poster of the answers had been posting a large number of word-for-word identical answers on similar reference-request questions. The link contains a referral, making it seem quite likely that the poster earns a small amount of profit each time the link is clicked. It is also plausible that he is (or is related to) the author of the book which is linked to, considering the short timespan between the publication of the book and the posting of the answers (merely $11$ days). All of this shows that the answer is likely spam, even though it seems perfectly legitimate on the surface.